# Cygwin bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: windows, bash, makefile, cygwin, eof

I have got a .rules file with the following command:

```
echo "char _$(var1)_b_[] = \"@(#) $(var1) $(var2) $(var3)\";" > $@
```

Processing this file by cygwin bash I've got the following error:

```
echo "char _a_b_[] = \"@(#) abc 1.2.3 [03/05/2014 064 01:10]\";" > file.c

_a_b_[]: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

_a_b_[]: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

On Linux it works fine. 
I tried to replace double quotes with a single ones:

```
echo 'char _$(var1)_b_[] = "@(#) $(var1) $(var2) $(var3)";' > $@
```

But it doesn't help for me. What's wrong with this command?

**UPD**

I found out the error is raised due to space character. The command

```
echo 'char _$(var1)_b_[] = "@(#) $(var1)";' > $@
```

failes, but this one

```
echo 'char _$(var1)_b_[] = "@(#)$(var1)";' > $@
```

is OK. Looks like bash thinks $(var1) is a new command and can't find needed quote:

```
echo " " > file.c
\ > file.c: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
\ > file.c: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Looks like a part of a Makefile?

Comment: The single quote version works fine for me in Bash. My environment: GNU bash, version 4.1.11(2)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)

Comment: Please update your question to show the actual `Makefile`, or a reduced version of it that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to offload the echo command to a separate shell script, e.g.

```
target:
        sh generate_code.sh $(var1) $(var2) $(var3) > $@
```

and generate_code.sh containing

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "char _${1}_b_[] = \"@(#) $1 $2 $3\";"
```

Comment: That works for me. Actually I didn't change anything in quotes, just passed echo commands to the script. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any ideas why passing the same commands to the script solve this issue?

Comment: No, I do not. My only guess would be that perhaps the `;` character was being interpreted as a command separator, but then it ought to be a problem in both cases.